# how to work with multiple buttons in JavaFX?

Tags: button, javafx

I have a question regarding JavaFX buttons. I have a set 4 buttons on my scene. The first three buttons are labelled **"Home", "Account", "Map"**. The last button is called **"Go"**.

I am using `button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){ })`

for each button to control the event it will trigger. My issue is that I want to click on one of the first three buttons (account, home, map) , but not action that event until the **"go"** button has been clicked.

*For example, I click on home, the button changes colour to show it has been clicked. I press go, and the action associated with the home button will be actioned. How do I do something like this?*

Another question i had is how do I ensure only one of the first three buttons (Home, Account, and Map, is clicked at a time. If I had first clicked "Home", then "Map" then "Go" I want to action the Map event, so home would be released when map is pressed.

I appreciate any help :)

Comment: I suggest you change the color and the value of a boolean for each of the buttons that have been clicked. In go button you check the booleans and perform whatever action. For the second part, you can just have a function to set the booleans of the other buttons that haven't been clicked to false. Hope this helps.

Comment: You want to use [radio buttons with a toggle group](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/radio-button.htm).

Comment: _why_ do you want to force the user into clicking twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noticed in the comments you can use `ToggleButton` (or `RadioButton`) for **"Home"**, **"Account"** and **"Map"**, and add them to a `ToggleGroup`:

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        ToggleButton buttonHome = new ToggleButton("Home");
        ToggleButton buttonAccount = new ToggleButton("Account");
        ToggleButton buttonMap = new ToggleButton("Map");
    
        ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup();
    
        group.getToggles().addAll(buttonHome, buttonAccount, buttonMap);
    
        Button buttonGo = new Button("Go");

        // Disable button "Go" when no other button is selected (remove this line if not needed)
        buttonGo.disableProperty()
                    .bind(group.selectedToggleProperty().isNull());
    
        buttonGo.setOnAction(e -> {
            ToggleButton selected = (ToggleButton)group.getSelectedToggle();
            if (selected != null) {
                System.out.println(selected.getText());
            }
        });
    
        HBox buttons = new HBox(5, buttonHome, buttonAccount, buttonMap);
    
        VBox pane = new VBox(10, buttons, buttonGo);
        pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

**Output:**

[image: Toggle buttons and toggle group]

If you replace all `ToggleButton` with `RadioButton`:

[image: Radio buttons and toggle group]

Comment: Thankyou so much! This was really helpful

Comment: I’m glad it helped ;)

Comment: Note there is a subtle difference between toggle buttons and radio buttons. More than one toggle button can be selected at a time but not so for radio buttons.  I think you can make a radio button look more like a regular button if you apply css to it (either the toggle button css or the [pill](https://gist.github.com/maxd/63691840fc372f22f470#file-modena-css-L675) css), though I have not tried it.

Comment: @jewelsea maybe I don't understand your comment correctly, but when you group toggle buttons in a `ToggleGroup` only one can be selected at a time. `RadioButton` extends `ToggleButton`, and when adding either a `RadioButton` or a `ToggleButton` to a `ToggleGroup` you can select only one at a time.

Comment: Oops sorry, I misrembered the difference between the two.  They do differ in behavior, not just looks, just something to be aware of. From the [javadoc](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ToggleButton.html): “Unlike RadioButtons, ToggleButtons in a ToggleGroup do not attempt to force at least one selected ToggleButton in the group. That is, if a ToggleButton is selected, clicking on it will cause it to become unselected. With RadioButton, clicking on the selected button in the group will have no effect.”

Comment: Good to know, I guess that if you want to make sure a button is always selected a `RadioButton` should be the best choice.